# Cross product commutativity

Tags: cross-product

I came across the definition of cross products, which:

$a \times b = |a||b| \sin \theta$

But I have also noticed that $b \times a = -(a \times b)$

I do not really follow, isn't

$b \times a = |b||a|\sin \theta$?

Clearly not.

Comment: The length of the vector $a\times b$ is $|a||b|\sin\theta$. Note that $a\times b$ is a vector while $|a||b|\sin\theta$ is a scalar.

Comment: we have $$|a \times b|=|a| |b|\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: One could also check the determinant definition of cross products, and the determinant has a well known property that if you switch any two rows the sign changes.

Comment: The angle is measured from $a$ to $b$. It will be positive with one order and negative with the other.

Comment: @amd that is precisely what I had in mind. How would the angle be different if we just swap the vectors around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing one part in your cross product formula: the cross product is actually $$\mathbf a\times \mathbf b = |\mathbf a||\mathbf b|\sin(\theta)\hat {\mathbf n}$$

And that's where your confusion is coming from because it's exactly that $\hat {\mathbf n}$ that is changing signs whenever you take the cross product in the alternate order.

$\hat {\mathbf n}$ is the **right-handed** unit normal to the plane containing the vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.  The term "right-handed" here means that if you were to place the side of your **right hand** (the part you'd karate chop someone with) parallel to the first vector in the cross product, $\mathbf a$, and curl your finger toward the second vector in the cross product, $\mathbf b$, then your thumb would point in the direction of the right-handed normal.

[image]

Using your right hand, confirm for yourself that the **directions** of $\mathbf a\times \mathbf b$ and $\mathbf b \times \mathbf a$ are opposite.  Thus the negative sign in the identity $$\mathbf a \times \mathbf b = -\mathbf b \times \mathbf a$$